# Display an UIPopoverPresentationController from a UIControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicontrol, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I am writing a UIControl. I need to display a popover when the user touches an area of the control. But of course the usual code:

```
[self presentViewController:self.popover animated:YES completion:nil];
```

does not work because we are in a UIControl, not in a UIViewController.
How can I display a popover from a UIControl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `rootViewController` to present it.

Use `UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController` instead of `self`

```
[UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.popover animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hi @trungduc It complains: Property 'keyWindow' not found on object of type 'id<UIApplicationDelegate> _Nullable'

Comment: @joan my mistake, it’s window not keyWindow. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @trungduc ! Works like a charm.

Comment: Congratulations ;)